# Polymorphism Implementation

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Let's say I have class A, class B which inherits A, and class C which also inherits A. Class C has method F, while class B does not.

```
class A {
    //Some stuffs
};

class B : public A {
    //Some stuffs.
};

class C : public A {
    void F ();
};
```

My problem is, when I have an object that I don't exactly know what class it belongs to (it can be either B or C), I want to check that object using a pointer of class A, and if that object belongs to class C, then I would like to call method F. How do I implement those classes?

I would like something like this.

```
A *_a = Something;
if (_a is pointing to object of class C){
    _a->F;
}
```

Right now, I am thinking of having that method F as a virtual method in class A, but I don't think that is a really good way of doing it, because only class C actually has it and if that is how I do it, for every method that I want in class C, I would have to add it to class A too. Is there any workaround?

Comment: If you have a pointer to 'A', then you can use dynamic_cast<> to figure out whether the object it points to is an instance of B or C. You can use the following syntax:
`if (auto pointerToC = dynamic_cast<C*>(_a)) { /*stuff*/}`. If you notice you need to do that often in your code, it is most likely your design is flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is indeed the design you want to stick to, you first need to have a virutal base (by for example declaring the destructor virtual in `A`: `virtual ~A() = default;`, then you can simply do:

```
   if(typeid(*_a) == typeid(C)) {
    static_cast<C*>(_a)->F();
}
```